# What things can I do at 4 am during 4 hours layover at the LCCT in Kuala Lumpur?

Tags: airports, layovers, kul

I have a flight from Goldcoast to Seoul  by AirAsia, need to transit in KL (LCCT) as 4 hours layover from 4:05am to 8:00am.
Is there anywhere I can relax and grab a bite?

Answer (score 4):

4.05 am ? Lucky to you - Starbucks in LCCT closes at midnight and opens at **4 am**. As alternative,  most fast food outlets (KFC, Mc Donalds ,etc ) are open 24 hours in LCCT.

LCCT also provides 3 hours of free Wi-Fi. So you can kill your time by accessing internet.

UPDATE : after did a pre-caution check, found that Starbucks in LCCT opens for [24hours](http://www.starbucks.com/store/5191).

Answer (score 2):

There's a [Plaza Premium Lounge in the LCIA terminal](http://www.plaza-network.com/location_detail?airport=Kuala%20Lumpur%20International%20Airport&city=Kuala%20Lumpur) at KLIA. It's not quite as nice as the one in the main terminal, but I'm told it's not too bad. They have showers there, so you can freshen up between the flights. There's free Wi-Fi, drinks, a buffet with food, nice seats, and it's open 24 hours.

If you have a high-end credit card, you may get free access to it. Otherwise, you can just turn up and pay, but you can often get it cheaper by booking online in advance